I am running below script in the jenkins, but i am unable to get the coverage report on the Sonarqube
container('golang') {
          script {
             sh '''
             cd src                                                                                
              go test ./...  -tags test '-coverprofile=coverage.out' '-buildvcs=false'    
             '''                                     
            }
        }

Jenkins Error
INFO: Sensor Go Cover sensor for Go coverage [go]
INFO: Load coverage report from '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/fed-inv-populate-test/src/coverage.out'
WARN: File 'internal/populate/remove.go' is not included in the project, ignoring coverage
WARN: File 'internal/observability/metrics.go' is not included in the project, ignoring coverage
WARN: File 'internal/populate/populate.go' is not included in the project, ignoring coverage
WARN: File 'internal/graphql/invoke.go' is not included in the project, ignoring coverage
WARN: File 'internal/populate/csvload.go' is not included in the project, ignoring coverage
WARN: File 'internal/apiendpoint/exposeapi.go' is not included in the project, ignoring coverage
WARN: File 'internal/populate/update.go' is not included in the project, ignoring coverage
WARN: File 'internal/populate/config.go' is not included in the project, ignoring coverage
WARN: File 'internal/logger/invlog.go' is not included in the project, ignoring coverage
WARN: File 'cmd/populate/populate.go' is not included in the project, ignoring coverage

Tried changig the coverage.out contents, But not working

I guess, but you do not provide a lot of infromation, that those informations are only available inside your container.
You should propably mount the $WORKSPACE folder to your container.
I also don't know if "container(...)" is something from a plugin which you are using. The standard way to deal with containers and jenkins are described here:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/
If you use the declarative pipeline, the WORKSPACE is automatically mounted into your docker container:
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('build go') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'golang' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
        stage('SonarQube') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'sonarqube' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=my_project_key -Dsonar.sources=src -Dsonar.tests=src -Dsonar.test.inclusions=**/*_test.go -Dsonar.go.coverage.reportPaths=coverage.out'
            }
        }
    }
}

